how to load csv file from a button in oracle apex screen, that should read data from csv file to table through plsql process code
I am trying to upload a csv file from a button from oracle apex screen , i have used the below plsql code in my process
declare
     l_file_blob  blob;
     l_file_name  BFL_SVC_PROCESS_TRACKER_V24.file_path%type;
begin

   SELECT filename,blob_content
      INTO l_file_name,l_file_blob
      FROM APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES where name = :P401_SOURCE;

    insert into a  select col001 ,col002
      from 
           table( apex_data_parser.parse(
                      p_content                     => l_file_blob,
                      p_add_headers_row             => 'Y',
                      --
                      p_max_rows                    => 5,
                      p_skip_rows                   => 1,
                      p_csv_col_delimiter           => ';',
                      --
                      p_store_profile_to_collection => 'FILE_PARSER_COLLECTION',
                      p_file_name                   => l_file_name ) ) p;commit;
 end;

But the data going into table is like below
1234,abcd,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 

What code need to be used to resolve this topic

You're not showing what data is in your file nor how you want it to be parsed (might be a good idea for your next post ;) )... but it looks like your columns are delimited by comma's and you're telling the API to split by semi-colons here: p_csv_col_delimiter           => ';',.
I'd say this is working as expected. Since the data does not contain any semi colons, the whole row is treated as a single column value. Try using p_csv_col_delimiter           => ',', instead.
Here is a handy trick for testing if the data will be parsed correctly:
SELECT line_number, col001, col002, col003, col004
  FROM TABLE ( apex_data_parser.parse(
                p_content => apex_util.clob_to_blob(
                  p_clob => 
'
"col1","col2","col3","col4"
1234,abcd,,
'
                 ,p_charset => 'AL32UTF8'
                )
               ,p_file_name => 'emp.csv' /*needed to get the file type*/
               ,p_skip_rows => 1 /*default 0*/
               ,p_csv_col_delimiter => ','
               ) );

LINE_NUMBE COL001     COL002     COL003     COL004    
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         2 1234       abcd                            

